# SQL Join on two tables with some conditions

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables. I want to perform SQL join, but not able to figure out how to achieve my requirement. Below are my scenarios and the result I want.

Scenario-1

CountryDetails table-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE123       AUS     null
 ABCDE123       IND     null
 ABCDE123       USA     null
```

StudyDetails table-

```
 StudyCode    StudyId
 ABCDE123      1
```

Result I want after join-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE123       AUS     1
 ABCDE123       IND     1
 ABCDE123       USA     1
```

Scenario-2

CountryDetails table-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE123       AUS     null
 ABCDE123       IND     null
 ABCDE123       USA     null
```

StudyDetails table-

```
 StudyCode    StudyId
 ABCDE123      1
 ABCDE-123     2
```

Result I want after join-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE123       AUS     2
 ABCDE123       IND     2
 ABCDE123       USA     2
```

SQL Inner Join-

```
UPDATE C  
SET C.STUDYID=ST.StudyID 
FROM CountryDetails C     
INNER JOIN StudyDetails ST ON C.STUDYCODE=ST.StudyCode
```

This join will work for first scenario but I am not able to figure out how to deal with second scenario.

EDIT:

Scenario 3:

CountryDetails table-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE-123      AUS     null
 ABCDE-123      IND     null
 ABCDE-123      USA     null
```

StudyDetails table-

```
 StudyCode    StudyId
 ABCDE123      1
 ABCDE-123     2
```

Result I want after join-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE-123      AUS     2
 ABCDE-123      IND     2
 ABCDE-123      USA     2
```

Scenario 4:

CountryDetails table-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE-123      AUS     null
 ABCDE-123      IND     null
 ABCDE-123      USA     null
```

StudyDetails table-

```
 StudyCode    StudyId
 ABCDE123      1
```

Result I want after join-

```
 StudyCode  Country   StudyId
 ABCDE-123      AUS     1
 ABCDE-123      IND     1
 ABCDE-123      USA     1
```

Comment: Are you looking for max StudyId?

Comment: Of course it wont, the `StudyCode` in `CountryDetails` does not match the `StudyDetails` table - this looks like poor table design.

Comment: I want to pick studycode which has "-" in it for my second case. Max will not work as "-" can be in max or min studyId

Comment: I know it's a poor table design, but can't do anything. Countrydetails will come from another system and I will store it in temp table and then want to inner join. Problem is StudyDetails table is already present for the application where users have added few studycodes with "-" and without "-". Now this system needs to be integrated with another system where I have studycodes without "-" and users are asking for result in 2nd scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should cover both scenarios

```
with cte as (
    select
        cd.StudyCode, cd.Country, sd.StudyId
    from
        CountryDetails cd
        join (
            select
                replace(StudyCode, '-', '') StudyCode, StudyId
                , row_number() over (partition by replace(StudyCode, '-', '') order by iif(charindex('-', StudyCode) > 0, 1, 2)) rn
            from
                StudyDetails
        ) sd on cd.StudyCode = sd.StudyCode and rn = 1
)

update CountryDetails
set CountryDetails.StudyId = cte.StudyId
from
    CountryDetails
    join cte on CountryDetails.StudyCode = cte.StudyCode and CountryDetails.Country = cte.Country
```

Edit: your scenarios 3 and 4 does not differ much from previous ones. You just need to change join condition:

```
with cte as (
    select
        cd.StudyCode, cd.Country, sd.StudyId
    from
        CountryDetails cd
        join (
            select
                replace(StudyCode, '-', '') StudyCode, StudyId
                , row_number() over (partition by replace(StudyCode, '-', '') order by iif(charindex('-', StudyCode) > 0, 1, 2)) rn
            from
                StudyDetails
        ) sd on replace(cd.StudyCode, '-', '') = sd.StudyCode and rn = 1
)

update CountryDetails
set CountryDetails.StudyId = cte.StudyId
from
    CountryDetails
    join cte on CountryDetails.StudyCode = cte.StudyCode and CountryDetails.Country = cte.Country
```

Comment: How can I use update on "countrydetails"? This query has select statement.

Comment: This really works fine. But I have another scenario where StudyCode in Countrydetails table can be "ABCDE-123" and join should pick the studycode with "-" from Studydetails table. This Join will keep studyid as null for this scenario. I am sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question.

Comment: How does it differ from your scenario 2? In both cases you have StudyCode="ABCDE-123" in StudyDetails. But in 2 scenario you are updating with value from StudyDetails, while in 3 scenraio keeping null?

Comment: and scenario 4.